# Cmake How to set custom ImageBase for my exe

Tags: gcc, cmake, clion

I want to set base address for my programm. I use gcc with cmake. How can I do that?

Comment: Does gcc have a flag for this?

Answer (score 1):

Start of the sections in executable may be customized with `-Ttext-segment=<addr>` **linker option**.

As for CMake, this sets start of the sections to 0x200000:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Ttext-segment=200000")
```

(Should come **after** `project()` call.)

---

Actually, given option just assigns value to start of the segment "text-segment".

It is default *linker script*, which places all sections after this address. It uses

```
. = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
```